# How to Update GCC to include C++20

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

This is likely a straightforward fix, but I need to upgrade my g++ compiler to include C++ 20 libraries such as <span> and <range> on Visual Studio Code but I am confused about how to do that.

From what I've looked up, to allow Visual Studio Code to compile with C++20 libraries, I need to run mingw-get update but I have no idea where I actually run that command to update the compiler for Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recent version of GCC+MinGW-w64 that supports C++20.
You can get it via MSYS2's package manager `pacman`, or if you don't need MSYS2 you can get a standalone version from https://winlibs.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be helpful, but I would manually change g++ versions in my settings.json for various cpp projects.

1. Open VS Code's command palette, search `>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` and select it
2. In the settings.json file search `"code-runner.executorMap"` and a few lines down you can change your cpp compiler version preference.
3. It may look something like this `"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++20 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"`

If wanting to downgrade to a c++17, you would just change the `-std=c++20` to `-std=c++17`

I'm sure there are better ways, but I hope this can be useful to someone!